# PHP email: passing over carriage returns

Tags: php, html-email

Hi I have made a very simple HTML email generated by PHP. This is fed by a contact form on my website. My problem is that where I have used a textarea box for the user's message, this does not carry over carriage returns into the PHP string. Is there anyway I can allow for this? because when I get the email through it looks squashed up. Thanks.

UPDATE:

My Code:

```
if(count($_GET)){
$name = $_GET["name"];
$company = $_GET["company"];
$mail_from = $_GET["email"]; 
$phone = $_GET["phone"]; 
$address = $_GET["address"]; 
$postcode = $_GET["postc"]; 
$subject = $_GET["subject"]; 
$message = nl2br($_GET["comment"]);
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_GET['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_GET['email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";}
```

then validate strings

```
if ($valid = true){
$finalmessage = '<html><body>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>From: '.$name.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>Company: '.$company.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>Email: '.$mail_from.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>Phone: '.$phone.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>Address: '.$address.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>Postcode: '.$postcode.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '<p>Message:<br /> '.$message.'</p>';
$finalmessage .= '</body></html>';

$to ='myemail@myemail.co.uk';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$finalmessage,$headers);}
```

This still does not work. Everything works fine BUT if the user uses carriage returns in the textarea, this is not passed over and the actual message is scrunched up.

Comment: what the content type of the email you're receiving?

Comment: can you update your question with some code?

Comment: Have you tried to echo the values for $_GET["comment"] and $message to see if the newlines are really getting to PHP and converted to html breaks?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `nl2br($text);`..

Comment: no this doesn't work as the \n bit needs to be inserted on each break

Comment: Then we really need some more code to see what your problem actually is.

Answer (score 0):

Newlines (\r,\n) won't make line breaks in html. Have you tried nl2br($userinputtext)?